# form validation through class

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am new to OOP. I want to use the values of class functions in a mySql query. But I am having difficulty retrieving the values. So maybe my method is not correct.

Below is my code and the result. As you can see, the echoed values are empty.

(If the attached code is not sufficient, then please let me know.)

**Code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['hidden']))

{
    $validator = new FormValidator();

    $fname =$validator->addValidation("fname","req","Please fill in First Name");

    $email= $validator->addValidation("email","email","The input for Email should be a valid email value");

    $lname= $validator->addValidation("lname","req","Please fill in Last Name");

    $pass= $validator->addValidation("pass","req","Please fill in Password");

    $con_pass= $validator->addValidation("confirmpass","req","Please fill in Confirm Password");

    $sname= $validator->addValidation("sname","req","Please fill in Screen Name");



    if($validator->ValidateForm())

    {

        echo $insert_query ="insert into registeration set fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."', email = '".$email."', pass = '".$pass."', cpass = '".$con_pass."', sname = '".$sname."' ";

         mysql_query($insert_query);
```

**Result:**

```
insert into registeration set fname = '', lname = '', email = '', pass = '', cpass = '', sname = ''
```

Comment: what form validator are you using? are they fetching the POST data for you? i don't seem to see where the values of the POST array are going into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Query you are using is more appropriate if you are updating an existing record try this

```
     if($validator->ValidateForm())
{

           $fname = $_POST['fname'];  // name of your input field 
           $lname = $_POST['lname'];
           $email = $_POST['email'];
           $pass = $_POST['pass'];
           $con_pass = $_POST['con_pass'];
           $sname = $_POST['sname'];


    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registeration (fname,lname,email,pass,cpass,sname) 
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$email','$pass','$con_pass','$sname')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

( edited ) and reason for not working is because your variables are equal to the instance of methods you are calling you need to make them equal to the input fields.

Hope this can help you

Comment: thanx alot kevin i changed my query but still it gives me empty values and my problem is still laughing at me. any other suggestion???

the result of the query is like that
INSERT INTO registeration (id,fname,lname,email,pass,cpass,sname) VALUES ('','','','','','','')